# jquery dialog with ok and cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery

in jquery dialog i am only allowed just a single button within a dialog. i want two separate button in this dialog

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                 $("[id*=btnclosejob]").live("click", function() {
                     $("#dialog").dialog({
                         title: "Job Close?",
                         buttons: {
                             Close: function() {
                                 $(this).dialog('close');
                             }

                         }
                     });
                     return false;
                 });
            </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnclosejob" runat="server" Text="Close Job"  />

      <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
            Are You Sure You Want to Close this job
      </div>
```

`Result` (with just single button "Close" but i want two separate button 1st for Action and 2nd for close the dailog)

[image]

when i click ok button it should redirect to other page

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add another button with comma?

```
$("[id*=btnclosejob]").live("click", function() {
     $("#dialog").dialog({
         title: "Job Close?",
         buttons: {
             "Close": function() {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             },
             "OK": function() {
                 window.location = YOUR_URL;
             }
         }
     });
     return false;
});
```

You can have as many buttons as you wish.

Comment: Thanks @GGio but how to change the text of button?

Comment: @SiddiqBaig just change the text :D. name it whatever you want, see updated